# Python, Telegram Бот

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Хочу понять как с помощью бота получать информацию со страницы сайта.
Проблема: Допустим, человек занимается инвестициями, у него есть пул из пяти акций. Чтобы мониторить их котировки, ему необходимо постоянно открывать мобильное приложение, ждать пока оно загрузится, вводить код пароль и т.д. Вроде и не долго, но когда это происходит несколько раз за день, его это раздражает. Нужен максимально простой телеграмм бот, который при запросе \Start выдаст актуальные цены этих акций списком.
Вот сайт с котировками - https://smart-lab.ru/q/shares/
Пусть для примера будет акция Сбербанка с тикером SBER. Остальные четыре я так понимаю делаются ctrl+c ctrl+v

Вопрос собственно в чем, как найти на странице какой-то объект (в нашем случае объектом является колонка "тикер" на сайте) и выдать его в бота

Ожидаемый вывод информации:
\Start
Цена SBER на данный момент = 132,87

В целом можно и всю строку акции выдать, если это проще.
Пытался гуглить, но подходящих примеров не нашел. Либо может вы знаете какую-либо статью\видео с решение подобной проблемы

Comment: А как у вас дела с пайтоном?

Answer (score 1):

1. Библиотека requests
2. Библиотека beautifulsoup

Comment: Забыли про Telegram Бот. В этом направленний хоть выбор есть. Про селенимум, Scrapy забыли у человека должен быть выбор.

Comment: Селениум в связке с телеграм ботом?) А про библиотеку для телеграм бота это очевидно

Comment: "Селениум в связке с телеграм ботом?" Кто-то парсеры пишет на селенимум.  "А про библиотеку для телеграм бота это очевидно" для кого-то видимо нет.

Comment: Селениум в разы дольше отрабатывает чем requests, в телеграм ботах это непозволительено.

Comment: Ну это не вам решать, а разработчику. Кстати глянул одним глазком на сайт, тут даже Pandas сможет спарсить, ну это так для разнообразия выбора